# Multiple IF php with 2 else statements

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo

I am trying to use the following code to 1st check if a user has a certain member level, then if they have a blog on the wp network. If they pass both those checks then a link is echoed, if they dont pass the first if check then another link is echoed. Also though, I am trying to check if they pass the first if but fail the second one then a different link is echoed. Here's the code I have now -

```
    <?php
if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(array(2,4))) { 
    if(current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
        global $current_user;
        $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
        if($blogs) {
            foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
                if($blog->userblog_id != 1) { 
                    echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'wp-admin/">My Site</a></li>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li><a href="/register-site/">Register your Site</a></li>';  
                }
            }
        }
    } 
} else {  
    echo '<li><a href="/membership-levels/">UPGRADE</a></li>';
}
?>
```

The code above echoes the register link when its suppose to but when the user has a blog, the register link shouldnt show but now it shows next to my site link. Any ideas?

***EDIT***

1. Free user sees a UPGRADE link
2. Premium Users without site see a REGISTER Link ( the membership array of 2,4 are the levels they have to be either one of )
3. Premium members with a site will see the MY SITE link.

***EDIT***

I was able to use the print_r and on the page where it's suppose to echo the register link -- Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [userblog_id] => 1 [blogname] => mysite.com [domain] => mysite.com [path] => / [site_id] => 1 [siteurl] => https://mysite.com [archived] => 0 [spam] => 0 [deleted] => 0 ) )

Comment: you'll find it becomes MUCH easier to debug this sort of thing if you use consistant indentation and bracket placement. I have a hard time even reading this code.

Comment: @Zach L thats why u down voted??

Comment: Yes, well that's part of it anyway. I down-voted b/c after 5-10 minutes of looking at (and rearranging) your code, and re-reading the question, It still wasn't sure what you were looking for, or where the problem was. A bit more time and effort into making your question, and it would have likely been an up-vote. If you make some improvements, I'll happily remove my down-vote.

Comment: well, I started to feel guilty for the downvote, so I editted your code formatting and took it back. Hope thats ok.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Wordpress MU documentation, I would guess that the `get_blogs_of_user` always returns an array, so checking on the value of `$blogs` exists is always going to return true. In the following code, I suggest replacing the simple check on the existence of a value with a check to determine if the returned value is an array and, if so, whether it has elements or not:

```
<?php 
     if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(array(2,4))) { 
        if (current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) :
             global $current_user;
             $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
             /*Check if we got an array back and, if so, 
               check if it has elements*/
             if ( is_array($blogs) && ( count($blogs) > 0 ) ) {
                foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) :
                    if($blog->userblog_id != 1) { 
                        echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain 
                            . $blog->path
                            .'wp-admin/">My Site</a></li>';
                    }
                 endforeach; // end foreach loop
             } else {
                echo '<a href="/register-site/">Register your Site</a>';
             } // end if $blogs
         endif; // endif current_user_can
      } else {   
?>
    <div>UPGRADE</div>
<?php 
     } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately the register link doesnt show. the my site link and upgrade link shows but not the register link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(array(2,4))) { 
if(current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
global $current_user;
$blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
if($blogs) {
         foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
                if($blog->userblog_id != 1) { 
                    echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'wp-admin/">My Site</a></li>';
                }   
            }   
    } else {
                echo '<a href="/register-site/">Register your Site</a>'; 
           }
   } 
} else {   ?>
 <div>UPGRADE</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried using your code but it didnt work. My first code snippet works for the "My Site" and "Upgrade" links, but the "Register" link doesnt show when necessary @FaceOfJock

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a shot. Even if it doesn't work in its current state, it should be easier to see the logic and figure out whats not working properly.

**EDIT**: Shamelessly stole [@JustinPearce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557748/justin-pearce)'s method of checking if the user has a blog from [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18788612/363701)

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
// print_r($blogs);
$has_membership_level = pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(array(2,4));
$has_blog = ( current_user_can('edit_posts') && is_array($blogs) && count($blogs) > 0 );

$registerLink = '<a href="/register-site/">Register your Site</a>';
$upgradeLink = '<div>UPGRADE</div>';

function echoBlogLinks($blogs) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
        if($blog->userblog_id != 1) { 
            echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'wp-admin/">My Site</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

if ($has_membership_level) {
    if ($has_blog) {
        echoBlogLinks($blogs);
    } else {
        echo $registerLink;
    }
} else {
    echo $upgradeLink;
}
```

Comment: thanks however the same occurs with all the other codes, the upgrade and my site link will show but the register link doesnt.

Comment: Ok, so I think the problem is then narrowed down to `$has_blog = ( current_user_can('edit_posts') && is_array($blogs) && count($blogs) > 0 );` always returning `true`, and not failing when the user does not have a blog. Safe to assume that in this case, `echoBlogLinks()` executes and spits out an empty `<ul></ul>`?

Comment: if I were you, I'd drop a `print_r($blogs)` somewhere and see what `$blogs` looks like when you want `$registerLink` to appear, and adjust that `if` statement appropriately.

Comment: where do I place the print_r? Anywhere on the page?

Comment: anywhere where `$blogs` is defined will work - see my commented out line near the top of my code example

Comment: I googled [get_blogs_of_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blogs_of_user) and found that it "Returns an array of objects containing the details of each blog the specified user has access to". So.... this obviously is not going to just tell you whether they have their *own* blog. You should probably totally rewrite this question with the *real* question, which is how to tell a *WordPress "network" user has their *own* blog*. Better yet, write that up as a new question, not bogged down with all this "Multiple IF php with 2 else statements" stuff.

Comment: thanks but I dont think that is necessary. The code `..if(current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
        global $current_user;
        $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
        if($blogs) {
            foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
                if($blog->userblog_id != 1) { 
                    echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'wp-admin/">My Site</a></li>';
                }...` works as should when using it by itself so Im not sure how creating a new question would help. It only seems to not work when trying it with an else statement.

Comment: Well I can promise you that code being executed in an `else` block does not behave differently than code elsewhere. Your are operating under false assumptions here. Why don't you start with *my* code above, put in some `echo`s and `print_r`s to get an idea about what variables contain what at different points in your code, and re-test your assumptions. Maybe give us details on how exactly you're testing this (3 different sample users?)

Comment: As noted before, `get_blogs_of_user` will return all blogs a user "has access to" (an acct with). Therefore this WILL NOT accomplish your goal (at least not directly) of determining if they are a "premium user with a site". As seen when you do `print_r($blogs)`, it returns *your* site, since the user is registered there. Saying the code above "works as should" doesn't really make sense, as it *should* work as described in the documentation which is NOT the way you want it to work.